# transform sql(oracle) to detachedCriteria(Hibernate)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I want to trasform this select to hibernate but i dont know how i can do it. I need select by group only the diferent dates (not hours).

```
select
        distinct to_char(fecha_emision,'DD/MM/YYYY')
from  TB_BCE_SIGPES 
order by to_char(fecha_emision,'DD/MM/YYYY') desc
```

I try to do but I can´t do more (I don't know how). I need put inside "to_char":

```
DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TbBceSigpe.class);
query.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("fechaEmision")));
query.addOrder(Order.asc("fechaEmision"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Projections.sqlProjection`:

```
    DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TbBceSigpe.class);
    query.setProjection(
            Projections.distinct(
                    Projections.sqlProjection(
                            "to_char(fecha_emision,'DD/MM/YYYY')", 
                            new String[]{"fechaEmision"}, 
                            new Type[]{StringType.INSTANCE}
                            )));
    query.addOrder(Order.asc("fechaEmision"));
```

In older versions of Hibernate you should use `Hibernate.STRING` instead of `StringType.INSTANCE`.